# How to show an application icon in the notification bubble?

Tags: application-development, python, notification, notify-osd

I'm trying to integrate my app with Ubuntu notification system. It works ok, but I don't know how to show my icon in the bubble.
My code looks something like:

```
notification = Notify.Notification.new ("Title", "Some text here", "/data/media/my-app-icon.svg")
notification.show ()
```

Unfortunately only text is visible.

Comment: Double-check the icon filename and make sure its permissions are set so it's readable by your app. `Notification.new` won't throw any errors if it can't load the icon. Also, any more code you could show us would help.

Comment: I noticed that icon works if I specify path like this: `notification = Notify.Notification.new ("Title", "Some text here", "/home/michal/Development/easy-stopwatch/data/media/my-app-icon.svg")
notification.show ()
` But this will not work on any other computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I figured it out. 
My icon is in `/data/media`, so I used `get_media_file` from `helpers.py`

```
from easy_stopwatch_lib.helpers import get_media_file
```

and then I did:

```
        Notify.init ("easy-stopwatch")
        icon = get_media_file("my-icon.svg")
        notification = Notify.Notification.new ("Title", "some text here", icon)
        notification.show ()
```

and everything is working.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the code directly, but there is this app called `Hello Unity` that you can install that teaches you how to integrate with Unity, including `Notification`. You can install it from the .deb. The link is below.

[Link](https://launchpad.net/hello-unity)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the link. I've looked at their code. Unfortunately I'm not able to understand how they made it working.